# Meaning of "set such store" (not a shop)

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

I can't understand this sentence:

> No other professor in Great Britain set such store by being called Professor.

In this case *store* is not a shop or a place to store something. I guess that the meaning is that the subject really wants to be called Professor and is angry if you don't call him so.

Comment: I think there's often a nuance of meaning in *set such store by* that's perhaps better expressed by *treasured*. So I personally would expect said Professor to be *downcast* or *crestfallen* if he weren't addressed by his honorific, rather than *angry*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Put store by](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+store+by)" in this context means "value highly."  Its usage is similar to "put great stock in."

Answer (score 1):

> No other professor in Great Britain attached so much importance to being called Professor.

The original sentence does indeed mean that the professor really wanted to be called Professor.

You can spin the sentence in various ways:

> No other professor in Great Britain ...
>
> - became so irate if not called Professor.
> - behaved so boorishly if not called Professor.
> - got as upset if not called Professor.
> - was as insistent on being called Professor.

And, no doubt, many others.